# MVC Razor call to @Html.Action() in VB.NET always calls the New() Sub, even if I'm explicitly passing the model to use.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, partial-views, ribbon

I'm building a Model in my Controller that I want to pass through an ActionResult on a different Controller. So in the Controller I have:

```
Public Class IndexViewModel
    Sub New()
        Ribbon = New Ribbon.RibbonViewModel
        etc...
    End Sub

    Property Ribbon As Ribbon.RibbonViewModel
End Class
```

And then in the Razor View I make a call to render it like so:

```
@ModelType ANA.Inbox.IndexViewModel

<div>
    @Html.Action("Index", "Ribbon", Model.Ribbon)
</div>
```

which goes to the RibbonController, which looks like:

```
Function Index(Optional Model As RibbonViewModel = Nothing) As PartialViewResult
    If (Model Is Nothing) Then
        Model = New RibbonViewModel
    End If
    Return PartialView(Model)
End Function
```

Before I even hit that first If(), I'm hitting a call to RibbonViewModel's constructor to create a new one instead of using the one I'm passing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not doing anything complex in Action, it will be better to use Html.Partial method to render partial view without calling action method

Comment: To solve my Action problem I moved the building of the Model out of New() and into a subroutine called Populate(), which I only call in the controller.  Now, while it still hits New() for each Html.Action call for no reason, it only populates it once and does seem to use that same model. Alternately, by moving the DisplayTemplate into ~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/ or ~/Views/Inbox/DisplayTemplates/, the Html.Partial calls works as I'd expect.